# How can I prevent my metal building from reflecting heat toward my patio?

Tags: heat

I have a metal shop behind my house about 20 feet away. This side of the shop is unshaded. The heat reflecting off of it is making my back porch unbearable. What can I use to stop the reflecting heat?

Comment: You could paint it black. However, that may make the shop so hot, it’s unbearable.

Comment: Maybe a sun shade, mounted on the two buildings.

Comment: Make it a wood shop? :)  Seriously, what color is the wall and roof in question?

Comment: The whole shop is silver

Comment: plant a row of trees or ornamental grasses between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a picture, this is a little bit of a guess.

If I were facing a similar scenario, I would get some shade cloth and rig it up a few inches or perhaps a foot off the shop wall that faced the deck / off the south wall (probably the same wall). This would diffuse the light hitting the shop in both directions, reducing the glare significantly. It would also reduce the amount of insolation hitting the shop, adding a benefit there. And bonus, it's available in different colors, designed for use outside, and relatively cheap.

Comment: It's the west side of the shop so it gets the sun from noon on.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is probably to shade it somehow.

You could build a screen in front of the wall, made from e.g. wood lattice, perhaps hung with netting or shade cloth as mentioned in another answer, or climbing plants. (I grow hops for shade and brewing, but the harvest comes a bit early in the year so a couple weeks around this time of year are unshaded but still hot.)

You could project a shade off the roof; depending on the angles involved, this may or may not cover the wall at all times of day. You'll end up with a covered patio space but will likely need a permit to build an overhang.

Whatever you do to solve the problem now, you should also plant some native-to-your-area trees so in 10-20 years the shade will just be there without any effort on your part. Evergreen bushes next to the shop wall, or deciduous trees further away if you find that the sun on the shop helps heat it in the winter.